# How to style my reactjs app running on chrome FreeBSD 23 ?

Tags: css, reactjs, smart-tv, babel-polyfill

I am trying to run my reactjs app on Panasonic Vierra Smart Tv browser. I am able to load the webpage after importing core-js and babel-polyfill, but the UI is out of place. The styling is not working as expected. The same UI runs well on chrome on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, switching from bootstrap 4 to bootstrap 3 solved my problem. Also, some of the newer APIs like fetch are not supported by older browsers. I had to switch back to XMLHttpRequest to make network calls. Everything else, including React(with Typescript) and firebase realtime, works fine.

I found the following two websites useful:

1) https://www.whatismybrowser.com/
   To check what browser or browser version you are currently using.

2) https://caniuse.com/
   To check support for a particular javascript feature across different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to embedded browsers all bets are off. They generally have old, inefficient rendering engines that support only a subset of CSS as we know it; run on low power hardware; execute JavaScript in interpreted mode and often have other deficiencies such as low maximum stack depth and a lack of modern innovations like hidden classes or cached property lookups.

These browsers are also often quite poorly documented. Even working with a manufacturer as a commercial partner you'll struggle to get much help. This is a problem because TV browsers are typically very buggy, rarely updated, and their low performance seems to compound their problems. I've seen rendering race conditions and all sorts of nasties developing for them in the past. They are a real pain.

My advice to you would be:

1. Stick to CSS2 styling features unless you can prove a particular CSS3 module is supported. This may mean laying out your page with floats and tables.
2. Do as little JavaScript rendering as you can. I wouldn't use React for this usecase.
3. Write your JS mindful of "classical" optimisations from the IE days: cache property lookups in closures; avoid binding new functions; be wary of stack depth (another reason to eschew React - components can invoke some deeply nested function calls)
4. Avoid transpiled languages. You need full control over the executing code because the performance of the runtime is so poor. This may mean waving goodbye to niceties like JSX and Typescript.

Overall if you are writing JS apps for TVs you are going to have to move a little away from a webdev mindset and more toward an embedded systems one.

Good luck!

Comment: Then how does the reactjs website which is also built on react work well on the same browser?

Comment: Because your react app is not currently exceeding the constraints of your runtime? Doesn't mean it always will - particularly when the stack depth increases. Set top boxes are not places to do extravagant HTML rendering. You cannot approach embedded systems that way.

Comment: The app is a single page app. The app is running but the UI is out of place. I have used bootstrap and I don't think the styling is working. The same css if I keep in assets and run an index.html page, it works fine. Only  after including it in my react component, the UI explodes.

Comment: @YadyneshDesai As I said, "When it comes to embedded browsers all bets are off." You are probably not going to solve this problem unless you can get a hold of someone at Panasonic. Your best bet is to rethink your tech stack to require a smaller surface area of browser features, to mitigate the chance of bugs derailing your application.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I guess you're right. I tried opening the AirBnB website and it throws me an error "Too much data to handle". But for my application, I am going to try using CSS 2 first. If that doesn't work, I will have to change my tech stack as you said.

Comment: Also, Can you tell me why I face similar issues in android webview on sdk 19 (Android 4.4) and below ?  The same thing if I open on the phone browser instead of webview works fine.